# Secure configuration in an unsecure environment

Tags: node.js, security, configuration, production-environment

I have a node application with secrets in a configuration.
But it is running in an insecure environment.

Is there a way to store the configuration in a way that it can't be read, but can still be used by the application?

Possible Ideas (still looking for solutions on how to do them)

1. Node can maybe required a password every time it runs to decrypt the encrypted password store.
2. <s>Compile the application.</s> (Apparently can only obfuscate, not compile)

If there are any other solutions or how to implement any of the above possible solutions.

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot compile a node.js application, you can only obfuscate the code, but that will by no means be secure.

Comment: You can maybe store the configuration in another server somewhere, and each time node starts get the configuration from the other server. (though logging in the node application reveal the configuration).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to store the configuration in a way that it can't be read, but can still be used by the application?

No, there is not.

If it can be read by your program, it can be read by anyone who has access to your data/code on the server.

Any secure container on that server or on some other server that you could store it in would need credentials to get into that container which would then need a place to store those credentials.  So, you have to have a secure place to store credentials in order to keep data secure.

Comment: This is kind of a deadlock situation, you store the configuration in another server and secure it using creds, you need to store the creds somewhere (i.e db or envs or anything) then again it can be read by anyone having read access to the application.

Comment: @AritraChakraborty - Yep, that's the case.  That's why the answer is "no" and why you have to have a physically secured server in order to have secured credentials.  Otherwise, a trusted human would have to provide some sort of startup credential (to unlock the stored credentials) every time the server was restarted.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, I am starting to realize that that's the best solution. Store all secrets in an encrypted store, on application start, user provides a password, through user input, to decrypt the store. That way the master password is only used in memory.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora - If this is an end-user app, then that makes sense.  A bit harder if it's a server that is supposed to restart on its own if it goes down.